# Check if file contains same text in consecutive lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, sh

I want to check if a log file has any instance where two or more consecutive lines contains the same text using bash. The text will be specified. The timestamp and any other text after the third field are to be ignored in the comparison.

i.e grep... "error" /tmp/file.txt

this file will match:

```
2020-01-01 05:05 text1
2020-01-01 05:07 error
2020-01-01 05:15 error
2020-01-01 05:25 error
2020-01-01 05:45 text2
```

this won't

```
2020-01-01 05:05 text1
2020-01-01 05:15 error
2020-01-01 05:25 text2
2020-01-01 05:45 error
2020-01-01 05:05 text3
```

Any ideas using grep, sed or awk? Ideally I'd like to have an exit value 0 for match and 1 for not match.

Comment: Do you know how to assign the value of a field to a variable in `awk`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with awk

Comment: _"I'm not familiar with awk"_ - then, why on earth tag the question with `awk`?

Comment: @Gardener. yes the timestamp and any other text are ignore. I forgot to mention that the matching text is to be specificied as an argument.

Comment: So you just want a yes/no answer?  Yes, somewhere in the file, we don't care where, the given text occurs on consecutive lines?

Comment: [uniq](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html) has all functionality you need for this scenerio.

Comment: @TedLyngmo by looking at some awk examples, I'm suspicious it can be done with awk. don't you think?

Comment: @MarkReed. Yes but also Having the command show the matching lines would be great

Comment: @ansanes I added _"The timestamp and any other text after the third field are to be ignored in the comparison."_ to the question. That's how I interpreted your comment above. Was that correct?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes.

Comment: @ansanes Ok, then I don't see how the accepted answer works since it includes the text after the third field in the comparison.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Not really sure what you mean. I accepted the answer because it points in the right direction even though It is not exactly what I was asking in the first place.

Comment: @ansanes I mean exactly what you pointed out. It doesn't answer what you asked for (after my edit that clarified what you want).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [uniq](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html) does everything you need.

> **-d**, **--repeated**
> only print duplicate lines, one for each group

> **-s**, **--skip-chars**=*N*
> avoid comparing the first N characters

So this should work for you:

```bash
uniq --skip-chars=17 -d /tmp/file.txt
```

Tested on my machine:

```bash
$ cat in.txt 
2020-01-01 05:05 text1
2020-01-01 05:07 error
2020-01-01 05:15 error
2020-01-01 05:25 error
2020-01-01 05:45 text2

$ uniq --skip-chars=17 -d in.txt 
2020-01-01 05:07 error
```

Comment: You could get the first line number where it occurs by doing `cat -n |` and adjusting the skip value, e.g. `cat -n in.txt | uniq -ds 25`.

Comment: This works. I use it like this: ```[[ $(uniq --skip-chars=28 -c -d /var/log/file.log | grep "error" | awk '$1 > 2' | wc) > 2 ]]```  to specify the text I'm looking for and the number of consecutive lines with a match.

Comment: OK, now you've introduced a bunch of other requirements.  `uniq -c -d` will get you only the duplicates with a count; the count will always be at least 2, but you're looking for the ones where it's at least 3. And then you're counting those and looking for files where that happens more than twice?

Comment: FWIW, you never need to do `grep | awk`.  Instead of `grep "error" | awk '$1 > 2'` you could do `awk '/error/ && $1 > 2'`. But that whole construction seems unnecessarily roundabout.

Comment: You also don't want `[[ ... > 2 ]]`; that does a lexical comparison, which means `[[ 12 > 2 ]]` is false because 1 sorts before 2. To do a numeric comparison, you want `((`...`))` instead of `[[`...`]]`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The idea is to check if the file contains 'text' in 'n' consecutive lines where text and n are parameters.

Comment: That doesn't do what the OP asked for, `I'd like to have an exit value 0 for match and 1 for not match`, so I'm surprised it's the accepted answer.

Comment: @ansanes Regarding [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74238301/check-if-file-contains-same-text-in-consecutive-lines#comment131070006_74238598) - don't do that as it's convoluted and fragile compared to, for example, a single awk command. Ask a new question to get help as this one wasn't a good starting point for what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

One in awk to test for *two or more consecutive lines* which to me  means to *exit immediately after two consecutive lines*:

```
$ awk -v s="word" '{    # search word as a parameter
    if($3==p&&$3==s)    # if third word is the same as from previous round
        exit ec=1       # and the same as the search word, exit right away
    else 
        p=$3            # else just store the last word for next round
}
END {                   # in the end
    exit !ec            # flip the error code and exit
}' file
```

Test it:

```
$ awk -v s=error '{if($3==p&&$3==s)exit ec=1;else p=$3}END{exit !ec}' matching
$ echo $?
1
$ awk -v s=error '{if($3==p&&$3==s)exit ec=1;else p=$3}END{exit !ec}' nonmatching
$ echo $?
0
```

In the sample above data only third words (or space-separated fields) are considered. If looking for a string longer than a word, consider changing `$3` with `substr($0,n)` where `n==18` in your sample (the starting point of string after the datetime part):

```
$ awk -v s=error '{
    if(substr($0,18)==p&&substr($0,18)==s)
        exit ec=1
    else 
        p=substr($0,18)
}
END {
    exit !ec
}' file
```